# SVG viewBox behaviour in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have this SVG and by using `viewBox` attribute, I can move in it and see every part of it.

[image: yellow box]

The yellow box you see in picture above is a constant 400x400 SVG and the width and height of it doesn't change.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="17900 -4100 1050 1050" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="400" height="400">
```

When I vertically scroll, Eveything moves inside the box but Internet explorer(11) behaves differently.

Like this:

[image: yellow box]

Even though the SVG height and Weight are 400x400 but the IE doesn't care and move out of SVG container!
How can Internet explorer draw outside of SVG element? How can I fix it?

P.S. In both examples, Only viewBox attributes changed.

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/omidh/unjq6h0c/

Chrome and Firefox draw all shapes inside the SVG element but Internet Explorer doesn't.

Comment: viewBox is changed how?

Comment: @RobertLongson by simply changing it in browser's element inspector, I've added a jsfiddle, please try it with IE and other browsers to see what I'm talking about.
For example change viewBox="19250 2100 800 800" to viewBox="19000 2100 800 800", Even if you don't change default viewBox attribute, IE may draw it outside the element

Comment: I wonder if the IE element inspector is working properly (it's probably designed mainly to work with html). Doing your tests without using that might give you different results.

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried  by using javascript to change viewBox.baseVal, Still the same... . Have you opened my jsfiddle in your internet explorer?

Comment: You should update your testcase to show this.

Comment: @RobertLongson Done!

Comment: I guess IE is just broken. You could try reporting it to MS I guess.

Comment: @RobertLongson Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be needed, but you can add `overflow: hidden` to your SVG.

```
svg {
  background-color: khaki; /* rgba(216, 210, 210, 0.06); */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I think SVG 2 is proposing that the default for overflow should change so it's good practise to define it the way you want on the outer `<svg>` element.